# List Permissions without Site Permissions?

Tags: document-library, permissions

Is there anyway to assign unique permissions to a group of people to a customized list on a site with unique permissions without granting them access to the site itself?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, break inheritance on the List and assign them directly via individual or group permissions.

Comment: Thank you, Trevor.  I thought I tried that before but my clients couldn't access the list until I granted them access to the site.  I am going to try and test again.

Comment: Provide them with the full URL to the List.

Comment: YOU are brilliant, my friend.  It worked!  Not sure why it didn't the first time.  Since my agency is still on SharePoint Server 2010, Enterprise version, I've noticed some instabilities.  Can't wait for my developer friends to migrate to SharePoint 2013!  One happy SharePoint Coordinator. :)